# MVC 5 Change the home page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, asp.net-mvc-5

I have MVC5 App which is running locally as expected ,when I run it it automatically
open the home page ,I have additional folder in the view that I can navigate to them
by specify the path(e.g.  `http://12.0.0.1:80/List/Index`  ) now I want to change it that when I run the main project (`http://12.0.0.1:80`) it automatically open the page which is `http://12.0.0.1:80/List/Index`  ,how should I do that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go into your `RouteConfig.cs` file in the `App_Start` folder of your project and change the default route constraints to `controller="List"` instead of `controller="Home"`.

Comment: Works for me too! Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use routes if you want the url to stay as `http://12.0.0.1:80` but with the new content

Use redirect if you want the url to change to `http://12.0.0.1:80/List/Index`